# Linux Error: 111: Connection refused LSNRCTL

Tags: listener, oracle-12c

I have a problem starting my listener, I am using Centos 6.5 and Oracle 12cR1.

Database has been installed successfully.

Now my issue is when I start my listener, the following error is shown:

```
LSNRCTL> service
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gaurav)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
 Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "tuts" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "tuts", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 Handler(s):
  "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
     LOCAL SERVER
 The command completed successfully
```

My hostname is `gaurav`

So i create an entry in `hosts` file as

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
 192.168.1.1        gaurav      oracle
```

Also, I have created a listener.ora file, with contents as follows:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =gaurav)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

sid_list_listener=
   (sid_list=
   (sid_desc=
   (oracle-home=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
   (sid_name=tuts)))
```

I am able to ping my host `gaurav`.

Can anyone please help me in fixing the issue?

**EDIT**

```
[oracle@gaurav ~]$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 05-JUN-2014 22:38:57

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr:  please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1 /network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/gaurav/listener/alert/log.xml
 Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=gaurav) (PORT=1521)))
 Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

 Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gaurav)(PORT=1521)))
  TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
  Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
 ------------------------
 Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                05-JUN-2014 22:38:59
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1 /network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/gaurav /listener/alert/log.xml
 Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=gaurav)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "tuts" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "tuts", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Well. oracle-home in the listener.ora is a typo - you also need to remove the leading space from your /etc/hosts just before the IP address. That's a starter anyway

Comment: @Phil:I have changed the oracle_home,and there is no leading spaces in hosts file.But still the problem persists.

Comment: Delete your listener.ora and use netca to configure the listener, then restart it. Did you create a normal database or a container database?

Comment: @Phil:Its a normal database,i deleted my listener and created it from netca,but now it does not contain any entry for `sid_list_list`,i restarted the listener ,still the same issue.

Comment: The DB should auto register with the listener. Is it running?

Comment: `The listener supports no services` ,this is an addition to the above errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14911/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-phil).

Comment: I had the same issue, checked the firewall, all of a sudden it was up, so it was blocking this tcp 1521.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like you did not start the listener but it is started. Your problem seems to be the tcp connection and not the ipc. So the listener is running, you can not reach it using tcp. Test this using `telnet gaurav 1521`

If the telnet does not give a connection, a firewall is blocking you. Stop/edit the firewall.

Comment: i have started the listener,but when i check the `service`,it is showing that error .

Comment: Are you sure you started the listener with this config? Did you set TNS_ADMIN?Is the listener process still running?

Comment: :Yes its running , i'll post the details ,once back from office .TNS_ADMIN is not set ,i tried to connect my application with URL ,not by TNS

Comment: can you telnet gaurav 1521 ? Funny is, failure is on tcp and you seem to fall back to ipc. Firewall?

Comment: @ik_zelk:Check the edit part sir!

Comment: @ik_zelk:[oracle@gaurav admin]$ telnet gaurav 1521 Trying 192.168.1.1... telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.1: Connection refused

Comment: stop your firewall on gaurav